# Elementwise comparison between two arrays without for loops in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one big array called **dataset** in Numpy of dimensions (700, 28, 28, 3). Suppose this matrix is like the one below:

```
>>> dataset=np.random.rand(5600,28,28,3)
>>> dataset.shape
(5600, 28, 28, 3)
```

Now, let's suppose I have another array, simpler, called **query** which I will use to search in the **dataset** array

```
>>> query=np.random.rand(28,28,3)
>>> query.shape
(28, 28, 3)
```

One way to search that matrix **query** in the bigger one is by calculating the mean squared error between it and all the elements of the array **dataset**. The smaller MSE tells me where the matrix is in the array **dataset**.

The issue is, I don't want to make a for loop in Python to calculate the MSE one by one, store the MSEs in another array, and then getting the position of the smallest MSE when the loop ends. I already have two for loops before this comparison and, therefore, would like to make it as efficient and fast as possible. Is that possible to solve such a problem without a big for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scanner function that scans over the dataset using `map` then extract the minimum MSE location from the resulting map:

```py
MSE_scanner = lambda A : ((query-A)**2).mean() # create the MSE comparison function
MSE_array = list(map(MSE_scanner, dataset)) # array of MSEs relevant to query
MSE_minimum = min(MSE_array) # extract the minimum MSE which should the one matched
query_location = MSE_array.index(MSE_minimum) # extract the location of the minimum MSE
```

Comment: my personal opinion tho, this is less efficient than a well written for loop, and the for loop I think the most efficient algorithmic way, any more efficiency would have to come from parallelization not algorithm, but I may be wrong, would love to hear other thoughts

Comment: You may be right about `for` loop being the most efficient. It might be faster than the three answers posted so far (including mine), because internally (under the hood, all of these answers make multiple passes (traversals) across a long sequence. (At least one traversal to compute SE or MSE or euclidean distance. Then at least one more pass to find the minimum of those.) With a `for` loop, in a single pass, you could compute the SE or MSE or euclidean dist, and also keep watching out for a "running minimum". By the end of that one pass, you can have the position of the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
se = (dataset-query)**2                            # Squared error - shape (L,28,28,3)
sum_of_se = np.sum(se.reshape(-1,28*28*3), axis=1) # Sum of squared error - shape (L,)
print (np.argmin(sum_of_se))                       # Position of minimum within sum_of_se
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), with the squared euclidean distance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dataset = np.random.rand(5600, 28, 28, 3)
query = np.random.rand(28, 28, 3)

res = cdist(query.reshape((1, -1)), dataset.reshape((5600, -1)), 'seuclidean')
print(np.argmin(res))
```